# Register interrupt to wakup system from standby?

Tags: linux

How can I register an interrupt to wakeup the system from standby?
I try to program an MCU to wakeup the CPU over a message to host.

Comment: Is "Wake on LAN" a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give more informations about your system and configuration. Several wakeup sources are conceivable as Ethernet, Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, GSM, ..